# General Definition of Steady State?

Tags: macroeconomics

Would this general definition suffice for any steady state:

**In steady state allocations and prices are constant (or growing at constant rate)**

So for instance if I define an Arrow-Debreu equilibrium with prices and allocations, I can for every price and allocation generally say:

$x_{t}$ = $x_{t+1}$ = $x$

Is there a standard agreed upon definition that I can always rely on?

Comment: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/25770/what-does-steady-state-mean

Comment: This seems to be duplicate of the Q linked in the other comments can you please explain why the answer there does not answer your Q?

Comment: The answers there says it depends on context. But there has to be a general definition in terms of competitive equilibria given allocations and prices. I think it is when per capita allocations are constant and real prices are constant, although it is possible for aggregate variables to grow.